# How to enable remote access [from MAC OSX] to MySQL server on Windows server

Tags: mysql, macos, workbench

I am trying to give database permission (to my remote Windows 7 MySQL workbench) from a MAC OSX 10.7. however I have read and watched videos doing so, in which the following code must be written on the `mysql command line`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

FLUSH PRIVILIGES;
```

however when i type `mysql` onto the MAC OSX terminal to gain access to MySQL command line i get `"command not found"`... Why is it not finding mysql? Is there another way around this from my MAC OSX workbench? I have the latest mySQL software as i downloaded them within the last month

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with permissions, but with the location of the MySQL program. In MacOS X, it is located in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`. Check if it is there. So, you should:

- Type, in your terminal: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` (followed by your connection parameters), or
- add `/usr/local/mysql/bin` to your `$PATH` environment variable:

  1. In a terminal window, be sure that you are in your Home directory (type `cd` and press Enter)
  2. You'll need to edit your `.bash_profile` file. 
      Type `nano .bash_profile` and press Enter.
      At the last line, write the following: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/`
  3. Restart the terminal app, and try again (you should be able to write `mysql` directly in the terminal, without writing the full path to the command.

Comment: thanks! it found `mysql`